# Customizing bootbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I'm trying to customize bootbox design. I have succeeded in getting the output which shows like below:
[image]

here my code is

```
        var dialog = bootbox.alert({
    closeButton: false,
         title: false,
         message: 'hello',
         className: "my-popup"
      });
      dialog.init(function(){
var message = $(".my-popup").find(".bootbox-body");
$(".my-popup").find(".modal-footer").prepend(message);
$(".my-popup").find(".modal-footer div").css({"display":"inline-block", "padding-right":"10px", "color":"#f7f7f7"});
 $(".my-popup").find(".modal-body").remove();    
});
```

this works well. but I have few more alerts on my page which I also want to show like this.
so I tried to minified above code or to set common properties for bootbox but after that my `init` function stop working.

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqbo9wxp/1/).
I'm using `bootbox.setDefaults` to set a common class and then trying to give alert but `init` not working now.
Is there a way through I can set init function after `bootbox.setDefaults`
so i just simply call `bootbox.alert()` only every time. not the whole code.

Comment: pls check `message` variable. it's empty

Comment: According to my code there is div in message variable which contains message. which i m putting to modal-footer. According to boot box message comes on modal-body but i'm trying to put message in modal-footer.

Comment: I checked `$(".my-popup").find(".bootbox-body").length==0`. It means there isn't div in `message` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check below mentioned solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  bootbox.setDefaults({
      closeButton: false,
      title: false,
      className: 'my-popup'
  });
  dialog.init(function() {
      var message = $(".bootbox.modal").find(".bootbox-body");
      $(".bootbox.modal").find(".modal-body").remove();
      $(".bootbox.modal").find(".modal-footer").prepend(message);
      $(".bootbox.modal").find(".modal-footer div").css({"display": "inline-block", "padding-right": "10px", "color": "#f7f7f7"});
  });
});
var dialog = bootbox.alert('Hello World!');
```

```css
.new-container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
}

.new-container h2, .modal-content {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  background: #ff4d4d !important;
  padding: .3em;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: Baskerville;
  font-style: italic;
}

.new-container h2:before, .modal-content:before, .new-container h2:after, .modal-content:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: -1em;
  border: 1em solid #ff4d4d;
  z-index: -1; 
}

.new-container h2:before, .modal-content:before {
  left: -1em;
  border-right-width: 1em;
  border-right-color: #a51414;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.modal-footer {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    border-top: none;
}
.new-container h2:after, .modal-content:after {
  right: -1em;
  border-left-width: 1em;
  border-left-color: #a51414;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.modal-footer{
  padding:10px;
  border-top: none !important;
  text-align:center;
}
.my-popup .modal-body{
   padding: 10px;
   color:#f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: What additional code you have provided as solution other than what OP created in a fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/dqbo9wxp/1/`

Comment: So you want individual popup for each alert?

Comment: yes, i have change the design for bootbox alert but it has to work normal. like alert. whenever or wherever alert call.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code**

```
var dialog = bootbox.alert('hello').addClass('my-popup');
```

---

`bootbox.setDefaults` set many of the default options shown in the bootbox dialog.But here the defaults('className') gets override when calling bootbox dialog.

To preserve the defaults you can chain a jQuery call

```
bootbox.alert('hello').addClass('my-popup');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/naz4wonr/)

Comment: its a simple alert for validation. On different condition it has to work. i can get this at work but my code is quite long for one alert. for e.g. first name, last name, DOB etc fields are there, i can not write 9-10 line of code for alert every time. bcoz my-popup class is not doing everything, Init method putting message to modal-footer from modal-body.